# ¿Como cambiar la target line en apexchart?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, charts, apex-chart

He estado usando apex para crear unos gráficos, puesto que me parece muy estilizado, pero no encuentro una opción y es hacer que un si un numero es mayor a un valor que yo le dé el grafico de área sea verde pero si es menor sea rojo y además que se vea como la imagen que les adjunto.
si pueden ayudarme con esto sería genial puesto que sino encuentro solución me tocará cambiarme a otra librería para graficar.

Grafico hecho en ChartJS

[image: Grafico de ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Hasta el momento no hay ninguna forma que haya encontrado para hacer esto, revisando la documentacion oficial no aparece como cambiar esa linea hasta el día de hoy, asi que si buscan como hacerlo anticipo que no tiene esta opcion.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Hola puse el comentario para que la gente este informada por si alguien tiene el mismo problema,para que sepan la posibilidad del asunto

Comment: La idea que tienes, es loable, pero es un comentario, no una respuesta, y esta es la zona de respuestas, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregarlo ahí, de esa manera cumpliría con tu objetivo, y evitaría que te "regalen" votos negativos.